# PHP Sum of mysql results calculated in real time dynamically

Tags: php, mysql, database, html

How to count a table TD as total using html or php or javascript or css?

Example

```
<table>
<tr><td> 1000 </td></tr>
<tr><td> 2000 </td></tr>
<tr><td> 3000 </td></tr>

<tr><td> TOTAL 6000 </td></tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

so build the table into memory first, THEN output the total. e.g.

```
while(... fetch from db ... ) {
   $html = '... table row ..';
   $total += $row['cost'];
}

echo 'Total: ' . $total;
echo $html; // output table contents
```

Comment: Nice... but no *signature* "snip"?

Comment: my right pinky has a mosquito bite that gets irritated by hitting `]`... so I'm avoiding that to keep from scratching down to the bone.

Comment: I always keep a 400 or 600 grit wet/dry sandpaper by my side, for just such an occasion. Mind you, a manicure would probably be nice. I've never had one, but they say it does the fingers good. *Healthy fingers, are happy fingers* ;-)

Comment: Any example based in my code? I am new to PHP sorry

Comment: Edited my question to make it easier to read and shorted it a lot

Answer (score 0):

Just for the fun of it: You *could* keep the output as is (at least the order, i.e. first output the items and then the total/sum) and then change the placement/order of the elements in the rendering of the browser by setting the [box-ordinal-group](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-css3-flexbox-20090723/#propdef-box-ordinal-group) in reverse order.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>...</title>
        <style>
            #container {
                display: -webkit-box;
                display: -moz-box;
                display: box;

                -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
                -moz-box-orient: vertical;
                box-orient: vertical;
            }

            #total {
                -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
                -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;
                box-ordinal-group: 1;
            }

            #items {
                -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
                -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;
                box-ordinal-group: 2;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="items"><!-- though it's before #total in the document -->
                <ul><li>a</li><li>b</li><li>c</li><li>d</li><li>e</li></ul>
            </div>
            <div id="total"><!-- #total will be rendered above #items  ...if flexible boxing is supported -->
                1234
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Empty result? You mean you didn't test my script but tried to put something from it into your script and it didn't work? Well, in that case you did something wrong ;-) If the browser doesn't support fexible boxing then simply nothing changes (which is different from "nothing is rendered")

Comment: I am using Chrome I put the css and id timed and total to mt table TD id like this <td id="items" class="headersubcustom"><?php echo number_format($mostrar['costo'] * $mostrar['stock'],0,',','.'); ?></td>

Comment: and after table added <div id="total"><!-- #total will be rendered above #items  ...if flexible boxing is supported -->
                1234
            </div> also tried adding a new TR and set td id=total and the same thing

Comment: Edited shorted and only english in my question now. Any help please

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer from @Marc B is the better answer to the title of your question.

If you want updates to your MySQL database pushed to your web page in real time, that's a different question - check out [Rachet Web Sockets for PHP](http://socketo.me/).

If you want a javascript solution that just calculates your total...

The HTML:
Add the same class name to each of the non-total table cells.

```
<tr><td class="amt"> 3000 </td></tr>
```

Add a span with an id in the "total" cell.

```
<tr><td>TOTAL <span id="total">...</span></td></tr>
```

The Javascript:

Get an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) of all the "amt" cells.

```
const amounts = document.querySelectorAll('.amt');
```

Get a reference to the "total" cell

```
const total_cell = document.querySelector('#total');
```

Declare a variable to hold your calculation.

```
Let total = 0;
```

Loop through the amounts, get the contents of each cell as a Number, and add the number to the value of "total".

```
for (const amt of amounts) {
 const number = Number(amt.innerText);
 total += number;
}
```

Then update the "total" cell

```
total_cell.innerText = total;
```

And the whole shebang...

```js
const amounts = document.querySelectorAll('.amt');
const total_cell = document.querySelector('#total');
let total = 0;
for (const amt of amounts) {
  const number = Number(amt.innerText);
  total += number;
}
total_cell.innerText = total;
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td class="amt"> 1000 </td></tr>
  <tr><td class="amt"> 2000 </td></tr>
  <tr><td class="amt"> 3000 </td></tr>
  <tr><td>TOTAL <span id="total">...</span></td></tr>
</table>
```